# high oil consumption and oil pressure, possible PCV system malfunction

Tags: oil, silverado, pcv-valve

I have a 1993 C1500 4.3L manual transmission. 
My oil pressure has been reading very high (fluctuates, but generally goes beyond the upper range of the gauge). I had the truck in the shop and the mechanic indicated the intake was gummed up because the pcv valve/system did not appear to be working. He replace the pcv vale, but I'm still getting high oil consumption and high oil pressure (didn't check the mileage, but I'd estimate more than 1 qt oil in less than 1000 miles).

I recently checked all the vacuum lines (w/o a gauge), they see to have plenty of suction. And to double check that I didn't receive a faulty PCV valve, I replaced it with a new one just the other-day. The valve covers both have new grommets, tight seal.

Is it possible the heads are just gummed up inside? Will running seafom through it help? 
Is there anything else I can do without taking the heads off?

Comment: Are you seeing signs of burning oil coming from the exhaust?

Comment: No not really, not anything noticeable.

Comment: If it was not for the disappearing oil the first place to look would be the oil pressure sending unit and related wiring.  Then the oil pressure relief valve.  Last would be blockage in oil paths.